# Kotlin Dao SELECT query show error kaptDebugKotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dao

I added this entity and select  dao query to my project in kotlin

This entity :

```
@NonNull  @ColumnInfo(name = "namee") val name: String
@NonNull  @ColumnInfo(name = "fav") val fav: String
```

and dao :

```
@Query("SELECT namee FROM my_table WHERE fav = 1")
fun loadFav(): List<Detail_Entity>
```

when I run my project I get this error :

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

When I remove "namee" and replace it with "*" project work fine. But when I write query like above I get this error. SELECT query with "*" works fine, but with other command like "SELECT column FROM ..." it will not work and I get this error. I'm so using "pojo class" and get the same error.

How can I use above SELECT query correctly?

Comment: Try to edit your query as `@Query("SELECT namee  FROM my_table WHERE fav = '1'")`. You should wrap the string constant between single quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this row

```
fun loadFav(): List<Detail_Entity>
```

it must be changed to:

```
fun getfav(): LiveData<List<Detail_Entity_selectfav>>
```

You must use the sub class entity that have same column that you want to use.

Like:

```
class Detail_Entity_selectfav {
    @NonNull
    var name : String =""
    @NonNull
    var imageName : String =""
}
```